# cloud foundry login authentication failed?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I can login to cloud foundry from the login page without problems. But when I tried cf login, I got:

```
C:\Users\pding>cf target api.cloudfoundry.com
Setting target to https://api.cloudfoundry.com... OK

C:\Users\pding>cf login
target: https://api.cloudfoundry.com

Email> ********* (my email address)
Password> ******** (my password)

Authenticating... FAILED
```

Anything I missed?

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found helpful solution for your question asked here... welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue and the solution I got is to switch to `vmc`. (I am on windows 64-bit and using ruby 1.9.3-p327 x64 build)

```
C:\Windows\system32>cf target api.cloudfoundry.com
Setting target to https://api.cloudfoundry.com... OK

C:\Windows\system32>cf login
target: https://api.cloudfoundry.com

Email> amol#####e@gmail.com

Password> ******

Authenticating... FAILED
Password> ******

Authenticating... FAILED
Password> ******

Authenticating... FAILED
```

After I switched to `vmc`

```
C:\Windows\system32>vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com
Setting target to https://api.cloudfoundry.com... OK

C:\Windows\system32>vmc login
target: https://api.cloudfoundry.com

Email> amol######e@gmail.com

Password> ******

Authenticating... OK
```

`cf` is not compatible with cloud_controller v1 and `vmc` only supports v1 systems... (sources ***[`cf`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf#cf---cli-for-cloud-foundry)*** & ***[`vmc`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc#deprecated-for-v2-cf-installs-cloudfoundrycom-uses-v1)***)
Happy exploring..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but they (cloudfoundry) could be a little helpful, right now the default pages for ALL 'getting started' pages states using 'cf' as a pre-requisite, it does not state that 'cf' does not work with cloudfoundry.com - something beginners will assume and subsequently fail. Even more unhelpful is 'cf' README also fails to point this out, ONLY the 'VMC' README points this out clearly.

Comment: For doubts which `readme` cannot answer, its better to jump into source at github. I have given the links in my answer. But I agree its bit difficult for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

**vmc** is the client for Cloud Foundry v1 which will be shutdown on June 30th I believe. To use it you need to run:

```
vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com
```

**cf** is the client for Cloud Foundry v2. The web console is available at https://console.run.pivotal.io/ (your v1 credentials should work).

To run cf commands you need to run:

```
cf target api.run.pivotal.io
```

Your v1 apps are not automatically migrated to v2. You'll have to do this manually. See the FAQ for more info: http://www.cloudfoundry.com/faq.